# Prove that the correspondence is lower hemicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

Define the correspondence $\Phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $\Phi(x) = [x, x + 1]$. Prove that $\Phi$
is lower hemi-continuous.

I am struggling with how to prove this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your definition of lower hemicontinuity stated in terms of neighborhoods, or in terms of sequences?

Comment: It is stated in terms of neighborhoods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that if $a\in\Bbb R$, and $V$ is an open set such that $V\cap\Phi(a)\ne\varnothing$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $V\cap\Phi(x)\ne\varnothing$ for each $x\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$. That is, if $V$ is an open set such that $V\cap[a,a+1]\ne\varnothing$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $V\cap[x,x+1]\ne\varnothing$ for each $x\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$.

I’ll get you started. If $V$ is an open set such that $V\cap[a,a+1]\ne\varnothing$, then there are $u,v\in[a,a+1]$ such that $\varnothing\ne(u,v)\subseteq V\cap[a,a+1]$. (Why?) We want to find a positive $\epsilon$ small enough so that $(u,v)\cap[x,x+1]\ne\varnothing$ whenever $|x-a|<\epsilon$. If $a-\epsilon<x<a$, that means making sure that $x+1>u$. (Why?) And if $a\le x<a+\epsilon$, it means making sure that $x<v$. (Again, why?) Using these inequalities it is not hard to express a suitable $\epsilon$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Sorry, I edited a few minutes after my original reply that this was meant in terms of neighborhoods. Isn't it easier to prove this in terms of sets instead of sequences? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @Anon: I’ve completely rewritten it in terms of the nbhd definition; this actually simplifies it quite a bit.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How would this be done when lower hemicontinuity is defined in terms of sequences?

Comment: @Charles: If you click on the link **edited Aug 17 '20 at 1:41** below the answer, you can see the original version of my answer, which was in terms of sequences.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. Is my response (using an alternative sequential definition of LHC) correct?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following definition of lower hemicontinuity: a correspondence $\Phi(x)$ is lower hemicontinuous if for any point $\{x,y\}$ in the graph of $\phi(x)$, and any sequence $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, there exists a sequence $y_{n}$ such that $y_{n}\rightarrow y$, and $y_{n}\in \Phi(x_{n})$ for all $n$.

On to your problem. Take $\{x,y\}$ in the graph of $\Phi(x)$ (this means that $y\in [x, x+1]$). Consider an arbitrary $x_{n}\rightarrow x$. Note that, for each $n$, $[x_{n}, x_{n}+1]$ is non-empty. Also, since $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ and $y\in [x, x+1]$, for large enough $n$ it must be the case that $y\in [x_{n}, x_{n}+1]$. Say that this is the case for all $n>N_{1}$.

Now, construct the $y_{n}$ sequence as follows. For all $n>N_1$, set $y_{n}$ equal to $y$. For all $n \leq N_{1}$, set $y_{n}$ to any element in $[x_{n}, x_{n+1}]$ (by the non-emptiness of these sets, we know that there is always something to choose).

Thus, we have a sequence, $y_{n}$, such that $y_{n}\rightarrow y$, and $y_{n}\in \Phi(x_{n})$, for all $n$.

Comment: First, a notational problem: $\{x,y\}$ is the two-element set whose members are $x$ and $y$, identical with the set $\{y,x\}$; it is not an ordered pair. Your sequential definition of lower hemicontinuity is different from those that I’ve seen, but it’s not hard to show that it’s equivalent to Definition $88$ in [this PDF](http://web.mit.edu/14.102/www/notes/lecturenotes0915.pdf) provided that $\Phi(x)\ne\varnothing$ for each $x$, as is the case in this problem. However, with that definition your argument runs into trouble if $y=x$ or $y=x+1$. Suppose that $y=x+1$, and ...

Comment: ... $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ from the left: then there is no $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $y\in[x_n,x_{n+1}]$. Similarly, if $y=x$, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ from the right, then there is no $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $y\in[x_n,x_{n+1}]$. In each of these cases it’s not hard to see that setting each $y_n=x_n+1$ in the first case and $y_n=x_n$ in the second will work. But in both cases it gets a bit trickier if $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ approaches $x$ from both sides. You can still handle that situation with your definition, but it’s a little ...

Comment: ... easier if you use [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity#Sequential_characterization_2).